# range.replace method doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what I would like to do:

- replace the words in `column D` of `sheet15` according to the list in `sheet1`
- in `sheet1`, `col A` housed the list of words I want to replace, and the corresponding words I would like to replace it with is next to it (in `col B`)

Below the code works fine when I try it in a new workbook but when I place it in my project, it does not.
I debugged it line by line, no error, but the words are not being replaced accordingly.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Does anybody here know where did I go wrong?

```
sub changeproc()        
Dim fromVal As String, toVal As String, cel As Range, lr As Long

With Sheet1  'validation list and replacement
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cel In .Range("A1:A1" & lr)  'ori list in col a
        fromVal = cel.Value2
        toVal = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value2  'replacement list in col b
        'Sheet15.Range("D:D").Replace fromVal, toVal, xlWhole, , True  'replace at data sheet

    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but `For Each cel In .Range("A1:A1" & lr)` should be `For Each cel In .Range("A1:A" & lr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine, just make sure u use proper sheet names. Check in VBA project, or to be sure use Sheets("name_here").

And (probably it's obvious, but just to be sure :P) uncomment this line:
`'Sheet15.Range("D:D").Replace fromVal, toVal, xlWhole, , True  'replace at data sheet`

Comment: Just found out where I did wrong...the sheet that has the replacement list is named sheet1 where in fact the index at vba page shows it is sheet2.silly me ..